# TypeScript: force type error when anonymous object property doesn't meet type specification

Tags: typescript, types

I've got an anonymous object with a TypeScript typed property. Something like this:

```
type Foo = {
  exists: true;
  bar: string;
};

doSomething({
  foo: {
    exists: true,
    bar: 'baz',
  } as Foo,
});
```

I'd like to type protect the `foo` property so if type `Foo` ever changes in the future (e.g. gets a new property), then the TypeScript compiler will warn me. While these cause compiler errors:

```
doSomething({
  foo: {
    exists: 'string', // Incorrect type
    bar: 'baz',
  } as Foo
});

doSomething({
  foo: {
    say: 'hello', // Not enough overlap with Foo
    bar: 'baz',
  } as Foo
});
```

This doesn't cause a type error, even though `exists` is missing:

```
doSomething({
  foo: {
    bar: 'baz',
  } as Foo
});
```

Likewise, this also doesn't cause a type error:

```
doSomething({
  foo: <Foo>{
    bar: 'baz',
  },
});
```

The only way I can force a type error when a property of `Foo` is missing is this:

```
const foo: {foo: Foo} = {
  foo: {
    bar: 'baz',
  },
};

doSomething(foo);
```

...but that requires me to unnecessarily create a local variable simply for the purpose of type safety. Is there a way to type protect the property of an anonymous object?

Note: `doSomething()`'s parameter accepts `any` and doesn't enforce any type requirements, otherwise I could rely on `doSomething` enforcing the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript 4.9 will introduce the [`satisfies`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920) operator.

```
doSomething({
  foo: {
    bar: 'baz',
  } satisfies Foo,
});
```

Until then, you may use another function to validate `foo` at compile time.

```
const validFoo = (foo: Foo) => foo

doSomething({
  foo: validFoo({
    bar: 'baz',
  }),
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20221011#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKEAeBLAZ2AIC4pgAnAVwgG5MoAjAQwrKIrwDsBzegX3roAJnADKcALYRgAC248AFBiwAzBGRVYmrMgHIWALz0AaBvygFmwQqrwQCsBGf4BKIaInS5C5Q3VwZABuzAA2eMLwcH7aOmxQBszGZlhuLu7o6ADGcFxEUCHhkQjIUIoBZFGuyAB8UAGZqlRcWTa5UJ5SMvK8iqw8ZMxcINWo-EA)